# Upgraded to 22.04 from 20.04 Now Ethernet Doesn't Work

Tags: networking, upgrade

I put off upgrading to avoid exactly these kinds of problems. I found a temporary work around that lets me get online for that session, but I have to do it every time.

It's entering this command:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
```

which gives me this output, and lets me connect:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 1663 (packagekitd)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

How can I permanently fix this problem?

Comment: If you have PackageKit-based GUIs installed, then you should use them or use `pkcon refresh` instead of `apt update`

Comment: If you have `systemd-resolved` installed, then you should fix its configuration (directly or via NetworkManager) instead of editing `/etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 1):

The error message you have given relates only to the second command (`apt-get update`) and merely indicates that something else, perhaps an update notifier widget, was accessing apt's database at the time you ran it.  Can be safely ignored, unless of course it happens continually and after reboots, but I can't see why it would.

Your primary issue appears to be that DNS is not working for you and that using Google DNS (8.8.8.8) fixes this.  This *could* be due to a misconfiguration on your router, or locally on your computer.

Making this DNS change permanent depends on how you configure network-manager - assuming you are using a graphical desktop, you would go into the network options for your network, and set it to use 8.8.8.8 as your DNS instead of what your router or your service provider provide.

Here's an example of where you would configure that (uncheck "Automatic" next to DNS and add `8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4`)

[image: Settings -> Network -> choose a network -> IPv4]

But I'd be concerned about other devices on your network and whether it may be an issue that you should solve with your router or your ISP